# Can't link command to node script file, no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've got trouble when trying to `link` a commant to a javascript file with `npm` on a linux machine. Just assume some simple script and `package.json`:

**package.json**

```
"bin": {
  "test": "./test.js"
},
```

**test.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("test");
```

**installation**

```
$ sudo npm install
$ sudo npm link
```

Doing this on a windows machine causes no problems. Everything works fine. But on a linux / Raspbian system it keeps telling me:

> : no such file or directory

I have already linked the binaries of node with:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

And to be sure, I've updated to the latest version of node, `7.10.0`. But nothing helps. The message still appears. I have no idea whats wrong ...

Comment: What happens if you execute `which test` and `\`which test`\` (including backticks)

Comment: @sgtdck First shows `/usr/bin/test` and second shows `: no such file or directory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, the problem seems to be the windows line endings. They needed to be converted to unix style endings. This was the only change I've made, and now it works. This problem belongs only to the `shebang` line, because the `node` interpreter itself has no problem with the original file ...

For this test I installed and used `dos2unix`, which convert files:

```
$ sudo apt install dos2unix
$ sudo dos2unix test.js
```

After doing this, the initial `test` command works like a charm. So I've change the file on the development version to unix style, so I don't need to run this anymore.